# Remove folder name in URL in Winhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, nopcommerce

I have 2 domain names: domain1.com and domain2.com.
I am using the redirect script in the root to redirect each domain to it's own folder. This is working correctly. The problem I am having is that when it redirects to a folder it shows the folder name in the url after the domain name: (domain1.com/subfolder1).

My question is how to remove the ""subfolder1" from the URL?

I've tried to find a solution to this and found some guides out there but none seem to work. I have hosted nopcommerce in "subfolder1"

My web.config file as follows

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domain1.com$" />
                     <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/subfolder1/" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="\subfolder1\{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: I don't know about M$ but you probably want to rewrite rather than redirect.

Comment: @Billk thanks for your comment but its not working